# gtkmm applications memory usage keeps increasing

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I have a client that updates its window when it gets data from a server. Because it is using ClearSilver templates the glade file needs to be loaded every time it receives an update from the server. I'm trying to do this by replacing the windows first child with a newly generated child every time there is an update. This works fine apart from the fact that the memory usage keeps increasing, and since the client needs to be running continuously this will become a problem eventually.

This is how I build the window:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "mywindow");
HDF* hdf = NULL;
CSPARSE *parse = NULL;
STRING newLayout;

string_init(&newLayout);
hdf_init(&hdf);
cs_init(&parse, hdf);
cs_parse_file(parse, gladeFilePath);
cs_render(parse, &newLayout, Render);
cs_destroy(&parse);

hdf_destroy(&hdf);        

Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create();
builder->add_from_string(newLayout.buf, newLayout.len);
gtk_builder_connect_signals_full(builder->gobj(), SignalConnect, NULL);

builder->get_widget("window", window);

string_clear(&newLayout);

app->run(*window);
```

The Render function that cs_render calls:

```
NEOERR* Render(void * ctx, char * data)
{
   STRING * layout = (STRING *)ctx;
   string_append(layout, data);

   return 0;
}
```

This is how I rebuild the window:

```
HDF* hdf = NULL;
CSPARSE *parse = NULL;
STRING newLayout;
Gtk::Widget* widget = NULL;

string_init(&newLayout);
hdf_init(&hdf);
cs_init(&parse, hdf);
cs_parse_file(parse, gladeFilePath);
cs_render(parse, &newLayout, Render);
cs_destroy(&parse);

hdf_destroy(&hdf);

Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create();
builder->add_from_string(newLayout.buf, newLayout.len);
gtk_builder_connect_signals_full(builder->gobj(), SignalConnect, NULL);

builder->get_widget("child1", widget);

// remove the old child
window->remove();

widget->reparent(*window);

string_clear(&newLayout);
```

The new window generated from another thread through a Glib::Dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

You don't destroy previous widgets. [gtkmm-tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-memory-widgets.html.en#memory-managed-dynamic):

> Note that if you never added the widget to any parent container, or
>   you did but later Gtk::Container::remove()d it from said parent, gtkmm
>   restores the widget’s lifetime management to whatever state it had
>   before manage() was called, which typically means that the
>   responsibility for deleteing the widget returns to the user.

So you need something like that:

```
Gtk::Widget* oldWidget = window->get_child(); //from Gtk::Bin
if(oldWidget) //I had errors when reparenting into an empty Gtk::Container
{
  widget->reparent(*window);
  delete oldWidget;
}
else
  window->add(*widget);
```